# Align to baseline with groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots

When using groupplot in pgfplots, is it possible to

1. Specify which subplot `baseline` applies to?
2. Set the total height of the plot automatically or to the height of previous plots?

Specifically, with the code below, the `baseline` is aligned to the first groupplot not the last, or most southern plot. [image: Baseline aligned to first plot not last]

Also, I understand that the height is doubled, however I would like the height to be the same as previous figures. I would prefer not to specify a height for all previous plots and just specify a width, so that here if I need to specify a height perhaps I can find the height of previous figures(?). However, when I do specify heights to both (uncomment the two lines) the two plots are not equal in height. [image: Height not equal between two plots]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        {\Large{\textbf{A}}}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \begin{axis}[
                    width=0.5\textwidth,
%                     height=0.5\textwidth,
                    xlabel=X,
                    ylabel=Y,
                    title=This is a title,
                ]
                \addplot {x^(1/3)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}&%
        {\Large{\textbf{B}}}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \begin{groupplot}[
                    group style={
                        group size=1 by 2,
                        horizontal sep=0pt,
                        vertical sep=0pt,
                        x descriptions at=edge bottom,
                    },
                    width=0.5\textwidth,
%                     height=0.5\textwidth/2,
                    xlabel=X,
                    ylabel=Y,
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[title=This is a title]
                \addplot {x^(1/3)};
                \nextgroupplot
                \addplot {x^(1/3)};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem, add a `name` to the second `groupplot` and use `baseline=nameofgroupplot.south`.

I don't have a good solution for the second problem. You can get the correct height (for this case) by adding `scale only axis` everywhere. I suspect the reason for the wrong height is that the groupplots are first scaled, and then they are moved closer together (`vertical sep=0pt`). Or something. The resulting total height is anyway smaller than the specified length. With `scale only axis` you can avoid that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        {\Large{\textbf{A}}}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \begin{axis}[
                    width=0.33\textwidth,
                    height=0.33\textwidth,
                    xlabel=X,
                    ylabel=Y,
                    title=This is a title,scale only axis
                ]
                \addplot {x^(1/3)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}&%
        {\Large{\textbf{B}}}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(sub2.south)]
            \begin{groupplot}[
                    group style={
                        group size=1 by 2,
                        horizontal sep=0pt,
                        vertical sep=0pt,
                        x descriptions at=edge bottom,
                    },
                    width=0.33\textwidth,
                    height=0.33\textwidth/2,
                    xlabel=X,
                    ylabel=Y,,scale only axis
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[title=This is a title]
                \addplot {x^(1/3)};
                \nextgroupplot[name=sub2]
                \addplot {x^(1/3)};
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Do you know if there is a way to find the height of a plot and then record it in a global variable? If so, I can then set my B figure to this height/2 and hopefully using `scale only axis` will still appropriately fix the height. (Makes sense now I think about the scaling and the `sep=0` as you say.)

Comment: It seems that recording the height of an axis in a register or macro is pretty complicated so your suggestion of just using `scale only axis` is enough.